# How to query within specific tags?

Tags: sparql, ontology, rdfs, swrl

Hi I am an Ontology beginner,

I have built an Ontology and saved the RDF file with rule enabled using Protege. I am going to build a web service that takes some inputs from the Ontology. The inputs can be provided by querying the arguments, class and property predicates under swrl:something swrlb:something tags.

For example: `IF age<5 & weather='Windy' & season='Winter' THEN InfluenzaRisk=High`

I need a query to retrieve `age<5 & weather='Windy' & season='Winter'` and another query to retrieve the `InfluenzaRisk=High`.

As SWRL, the **antecedent** is placed within this tags swrl:body and **consequent** is placed within this tags swrl:head.

I have tried these queries below but it takes parameters in both antecedent and consequent. I am expecting that there is a way to narrow down the scope of query search only in swrl:body or in swrl:head.

Are there any ways to do this?

```
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject swrl:argument1 ?object }
ORDER BY ?subject ?object
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject swrl:argument2 ?object }
ORDER BY ?subject ?object
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject swrl:propertyPredicate ?object }
ORDER BY ?subject ?object
```

Below I attach one shortest rule in the ontology.

```
<rdf:Description>
    <swrla:isRuleEnabled rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">true</swrla:isRuleEnabled>
    <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Anthrax risk to non-vegan</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">AnthraxRisk4</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Imp"/>
    <swrl:body>
        <rdf:Description>
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
            <rdf:first>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#ClassAtom"/>
                    <swrl:classPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#Person"/>
                    <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#allperson"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
                    <rdf:first>
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#IndividualPropertyAtom"/>
                            <swrl:propertyPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#hasHabits"/>
                            <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#allperson"/>
                            <swrl:argument2 rdf:resource="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#EatingMeats"/>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </rdf:first>
                    <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:rest>
        </rdf:Description>
    </swrl:body>
    <swrl:head>
        <rdf:Description>
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
            <rdf:first>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#BuiltinAtom"/>
                    <swrl:builtin rdf:resource="http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl#select"/>
                    <swrl:arguments rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.vhynaulia.com/revalina/ontologies/2016/10/pwidas#allperson"/>
                    </swrl:arguments>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
        </rdf:Description>
    </swrl:head>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Any reason for using SPARQL in your web service and not OWL API or even better the SWRL API which both have proper Java objects for an SWRL rule?

Comment: No reason so far @AKSW, I am still learning using OWL API 5. Would that be easier to narrow down the query scope within the body or head tags, if I use SWRL API?

Comment: From my point of view, yes. SPARQL is low level and primarily designed for querying RDF data. OWL axiom and in fact an SWRL rule is an OWL axiom (at least in OWL API) are represented as a set of triples, thus, querying can become pretty much complex. IF you use OWL API, you have an object called `SWRLRule` which itself has methods `head()` and `body()` to get head and body of a rule, see http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/SWRLRule.html . Head and body are made of `SWRLAtom` objects, and so on and so forth...

Comment: Great! I do really appreciate your replies and helps @AKSW (y)